# Ruby version 2.3.1 the bundle install shows error

Tags: ruby, windows

```
  C:\Sites\addfee>rails s
```

Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5.1) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources        in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

```
then I did this
C:\Sites\addfee>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies.............................................
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
 Invalid argument - C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
 Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler    cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: What do the log files say?